# Store value from Userform into Excel Table

Tags: vba, excel

First off I'm very sorry if this is a duplicate, I've been searching **Stackoverflow** and **Google** but not having much luck finding what I need.

How do I store the value from a **`Userform`** text box into a Table in Excel with VBA?

My Vars are called:

```
Userform text box - TxBox_Building.text
Table Range - Range("Table5[BLDG]")  
Table Row long - lRow
```

So in Table5 Column with Heading BLDG, at row lRow I would like to put the value of TxBox_Building.text

I'm just not sure how to reference the correct cell.
I've seen many ways to store Userform data with direct references ( ie. `Sheet1 cell A5`)

But don't know how to use a Formatted Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Table5.DataBodyRange.Cells(lRow, Table5.ListColumns("BLDG").Index) = TxBox_Building.Text
```

If **Table5** is not working, you can use as follow:

```
Sheets("sheetname").ListObjects("Table5")
```